# Check OpenCL vendor ID at kernel-compile-time?

Tags: c-preprocessor, opencl, nvidia, compatibility

In an OpenCL kernel, I want to do one thing if targeting NVIDIA GPUs, and another thing otherwise, i.e.

```
#if MAGIC_HERE
asm("some ptx code");
#else
// some OpenCL C code which does the same thing, sort of
#endif
```

What should I put instead of `MAGIC_HERE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 options:

- use one of the nvidia-specific extensions, that is always present on Nvidia GPUs but not on GPUs from other vendors, for example `MAGIC_HERE`=`cl_nv_pragma_unroll`:

  ```
  #if cl_nv_pragma_unroll
  // NVIDIA-only code
  #else
  // Non-NVIDIA code
  #endif
  ```
- embed `#define MAGIC_HERE` into the runtime-compiled OpenCL C code string in C++, if and only if `cl_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VENDOR>()` contains `NVIDIA`

Comment: The second approach is "cheating", i.e. it makes assumptions I don't want my kernel to make; the first approach seems sound enough.